# Почему не всегда срабатывает include в Django

Tags: django

Всем привет.

По какой-то причине, не всегда срабатывает `include` в `Django`. 
Есть подозрение, что по причине какой-то ошибки, но как её пофиксить, я не знаю.

Сам шаблон:

```
{% load static compress %} 
    {% compress js %}
    <script type="text/javascript" data-turbolinks-eval="false" defer src="{% static 'js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" data-turbolinks-eval="false" defer src="{% static 'js/bootstrap-3.3.7.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" data-turbolinks-eval="false" defer src="{% static 'js/cookie-2.1.4.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" data-turbolinks-eval="false" defer src="{% static 'js/jquery.sticky.js' %}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" data-turbolinks-eval="false" defer src="{% static 'js/jquery.ajaxchimp.js' %}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" data-turbolinks-eval="false" defer src="{% static 'js/jquery.app.js' %}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" data-turbolinks-eval="false" defer src="{% static 'js/switcher.js' %}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" data-turbolinks-eval="false" defer src="{% static 'js/parsley.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" data-turbolinks-eval="false" defer src="{% static 'turbolinks/turbolinks.js' %}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" data-turbolinks-eval="false" defer src="{% static 'js/respond-1.4.2.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" data-turbolinks-eval="false" defer src="{% static 'js/raven.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" data-turbolinks-eval="false" defer src="{% static 'js/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" data-turbolinks-eval="false" defer src="{% static 'js/analytics.js' %}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" data-turbolinks-eval="false" defer src="{% static 'js/watch.js' %}"></script>
    <!-- js placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <!--script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script-->
    {% endcompress %}
    {% compress js %}
    <script type="text/javascript" data-turbolinks-eval="false" defer src="{% static 'js/csrf.js' %}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" data-turbolinks-eval="false" defer src="{% static 'js/jquery.easing.1.3.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" data-turbolinks-eval="false" defer src="{% static 'js/jquery.form.validator.2.3.26.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" data-turbolinks-eval="false" defer src="{% static 'js/jquery.inputmask.3.3.4.min.js' %}"></script>
    {% endcompress %}
    {% compress js inline %}
    <script>
      var loadDeferredStyles = function() {
        var addStylesNode = document.getElementById("deferred-styles");
        var replacement = document.createElement("div");
        replacement.innerHTML = addStylesNode.textContent;
        document.body.appendChild(replacement)
        addStylesNode.parentElement.removeChild(addStylesNode);
      };
      var raf = requestAnimationFrame || mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
          webkitRequestAnimationFrame || msRequestAnimationFrame;
      if (raf) raf(function() { window.setTimeout(loadDeferredStyles, 0); });
      else window.addEventListener('load', loadDeferredStyles);
    </script>

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 tooltipss and media queries -->
        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
          <script src="{% static 'js/html5shiv-printshiv.js' %}"></script>
          <script src="{% static 'js/respond-1.4.2.min.js' %}"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <script>
    function defer(method) {
        if (window.inputmask)
            method();
        else
            setTimeout(function() { defer(method) }, 50);
    }
    </script>
    {% endcompress %}

    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
    <script type="text/javascript" data-turbolinks-eval="false" defer src="{% url 'admin:jsi18n' %}"></script>
    {% endif %}
```

Сам include:

```
{% block js %}
    {% include 'includes/js.html' %}
{% endblock js %}
```

Пробовал выводить без `{% block js %}` - суть не меняется.

```
./manage.py compress --traceback --force
```

ругается на ошибки в других шаблонах, но на этот - нет. Результат команды:

```
Found 'compress' tags in:
    /var/www/gglobal/gglobal/templates/includes/css_head.html
    /var/www/gglobal/gglobal/templates/includes/js.html
Compressing... done
```

Внутри шаблона производились небольшие манипуляции, до которых он нормально инклюдился.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема действительно в ошибке в шаблоне.

```
./manage.py compress --traceback --force
```

Выводит нужный результат, но без --force отдавал исключение.

Но я так и не понял это особенность `Django` и тэга `include` или же так на ситуацию влияет ошибка после тэга `{% compress %}` внутри этого шаблона.